# OpenAPI Generator for Java RestTemplate - Change field name case strategy

Tags: resttemplate, openapi-generator, kebab-case

The OpenAPI Generator for RestTemplate currently produces entity models that have `@JsonProperty` on getters and setters that use camelCase. There doesn't seem to be a configuration option to customise this to use other cases like snake or kebab case. How can I override this behaviour?